# How can i add Jbutton on Jtable cell?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

i have a jtable where i can put some records but now i want to insert jbutton in place of that records

my code is given below

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class ScrollableJTable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ScrollableJTable();
    }
    public ScrollableJTable() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Creating a Scrollable JTable!");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        String data[][] = {
            {
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First"
            },
        };
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        String col[] = {
            "Roll", "Name", "State", "country", "Math", "Marks", "Grade"
        };
        JTable table = new JTable(data, col);
        JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
        header.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        int xSize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());
        int ySize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight());
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        panel.add(pane);
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.setSize(xSize, ySize);
        table.setSize(xSize, ySize);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a button is a column then you need to create a custom renderer and editor for the column. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on - [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for some basic information.

Then check out [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for one approach.